# Find valid time period for given date

Tags: sql, database

I issue is to find valid price for given date using two SQL tables.
First table columns look like:

```
Item_ID | Date
```

and the second is like:

```
Item_ID | FromDate1 | Price1 | FromDate2 | Price2 | FromDate3 | Price3 | FromDate4 | Price4 | EndDate
```

I want to write Query, where the result will be like :

```
Item_ID | Date | Valid_Price
```

As you probably guessed Valid_Price depends on the date. E.g.

> If first.FromDate(x) < second.Date < first.FromDate(x+1)
>
> result.Valid_Price = first.Price(x)

Of course Item_ID must be the same in both tables, but I know i can do it with WHERE or ON. Do You have any ideas how to include above conditions in SQL query?

P.S. sometimes only few columns are filled. E.g. there might be only FromDate1, Price1, EndDate, and rest of values are NULLs.

Comment: Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tag.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: if possible, I'd restructure your second table as follows:

Item ID, Price, PriceStart, PriceEnd

What if you have five different prices? you need to change your database structure then. Also, it would make solving this problem trivial

Comment: It is not possible, restructuring this database is not my competence, that's main issue. If there are 5 different prices I have to find price, valid for given date. PS Sorry for these tags.

Comment: Create a view that returns data the way as @SEarle1986 suggested.

Comment: Could You tell me how to construct that view. I have no idea

Comment: I reckon a CASE statement MAY get you what you want, I'd have to have a go though

Comment: As others have said, you need to tag the database you are using (MySQL, SQL server etc) as it could affect the query

Comment: What does the EndDate column do? can you post some sample data?

Comment: I use SQL-server.

Comment: FromDate1 Price1 FromDate2 Price2 FromDate3 Price3 FromDate4 Price4 FromDate5 Price5 FromDate6 Price6 EndDate
2009-07-14 00:00:00 11,26 2010-02-24 00:00:00 7,92 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 2012-12-31 23:59:00

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format this data above. E.G If FromDate3-FromDate6 are NULLs EndDate shows when Price2 is valid. It is valid from FromDate2 to EndDate in this case. And Price1 is valid for dates from FromDate1 to FromDate2

Comment: and what date would be there in first table out of fromdate1,fromdate2,fromdate3 etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is not the best solution regarding the query, but this might be functional :

```
  SELECT Item_ID, first.date,
         CASE WHEN first.date <= FromDate1 THEN Price1
              WHEN first.date <= FromDate2 THEN Price2
              WHEN first.date <= FromDate3 THEN Price3
              WHEN first.date <= FromDate4 THEN Price4
         ELSE 0
         END AS price
    FROM first JOIN second USING (Item_ID);
```

Hope this help. But not sure to understand your "first.FromDate(x+1)"

Answer (score 0):

Case statement was very helpful. This block of code finally looks like:

```
     CASE WHEN first.[Date] >= FromDate6 THEN Price6
          WHEN first.[Date] >= FromDate5 THEN Price5
          WHEN first.[Date] >= FromDate4 THEN Price4
          WHEN first.[Date] >= FromDate3 THEN Price3
          WHEN first.[Date] >= FromDate2 THEN Price2
          WHEN first.[Date] >= FromDate1 THEN Price1  
          ELSE NULL
     END AS price
```

(...)

```
ON FIRST.[Date] <= EndDate
```